# d3.js: distance point to svg:path

Tags: d3.js

Is there an (efficient) method to (a) calculate the shortest distance between a fixed point and a svg:path element in d3.js and (b) determine the point on the path which belongs to this distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, I don´t think so. An SVG path is a complex element. For instance, if the path is a Bezier curve, the control points may be off the represented line, and the represented shape may be off the bounding box of the control points.

I think that if you have a set of points that you use to generate the path, you may use this points to compute the distance from this points to a given point and get the minimum distance. In the [MDN SVG Path Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) you can find some examples of complex shapes and how they are made.

Answer (score 3):

Although my calculus answer is still valid, you could just do [everything in this bl.ocks example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8027637):

```js
var points = [[4, 76],[86, 133],[178, 128],[238, 123],[141, 38],[47, 20],[89, 88],[146, 27],[185, 8],[182, 112]];

var width =300,
  height = 150;

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("cardinal");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);


var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("id", "myPath")
  .datum(points)
  .attr("d", line);

var line = svg.append("line");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", -10)
  .attr("cy", -10)
  .attr("r", 3.5);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

function mousemoved() {
  var m = d3.mouse(this),
    p = closestPoint(path, m);
  line.attr("x1", p[0]).attr("y1", p[1]).attr("x2", m[0]).attr("y2", m[1]);
  circle.attr("cx", p[0]).attr("cy", p[1]);
}

function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {
  pathNode = pathNode[0][0]
  var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength(),
    precision = pathLength / pathNode.getPathData().length * .125,
    best,
    bestLength,
    bestDistance = Infinity;

  // linear scan for coarse approximation
  for (var scan, scanLength = 0, scanDistance; scanLength <= pathLength; scanLength += precision) {
    if ((scanDistance = distance2(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = scan, bestLength = scanLength, bestDistance = scanDistance;
    }
  }

  // binary search for precise estimate
  precision *= .5;
  while (precision > .5) {
    var before,
      after,
      beforeLength,
      afterLength,
      beforeDistance,
      afterDistance;
    if ((beforeLength = bestLength - precision) >= 0 && (beforeDistance = distance2(before = pathNode.getPointAtLength(beforeLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = before, bestLength = beforeLength, bestDistance = beforeDistance;
    } else if ((afterLength = bestLength + precision) <= pathLength && (afterDistance = distance2(after = pathNode.getPointAtLength(afterLength))) < bestDistance) {
      best = after, bestLength = afterLength, bestDistance = afterDistance;
    } else {
      precision *= .5;
    }
  }

  best = [best.x, best.y];
  best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDistance);
  return best;

  function distance2(p) {
    var dx = p.x - point[0],
      dy = p.y - point[1];
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  }
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

circle {
  fill: red;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  cursor: crosshair;
  pointer-events: all;
}

svg{
border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And I spent all that time in the previous answer writing up pretty LaTeX!

Comment: Additional Reference: https://github.com/cdaringe/d3-svg-path-editor. You can play with it [here](https://cdaringe.github.io/d3-svg-path-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a d3-specific solution to this. But if your path can be represented as a segment of a function, there is hope with a little calculus.

1. Start with the line length equation [image: length equation].
2. Plug in your point to x1 and y1.
3. Replace the remaining y with the function representing your path.
4. Simplify, then calculate the derivative [image: dd/dx].
5. Set [image: dd/dx] to 0 and solve. Hopefully one x value will be within the bounds of your path endpoints. Apply this x to your path function and you have your point on the path.

[A more visual example.](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/differential-calculus/48-49-shortest-distance-from-a-point-to-a-curve-by-maxima-and-minima) There are plenty of considerations to make this happen in JavaScript: what is my function? What is the fastest way to take a derivative of the above? These are specific to your situation.